# How to create row data for a date range with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

The table looks like this:

```
---+------------+------------+---------
id | start_date | end_date   | amount |
---+------------+------------+---------
 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100    |
---+------------+------------+---------
```

I want to change the table above to the following.

```
---+------------+------------+--------+---------------+
id | start_date | end_date   | amount | operation_date|
---+------------+------------+--------+---------------+
 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100    | 2021-01-01    |
 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100    | 2021-01-02    |
 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100    | 2021-01-03    |
 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100    | 2021-01-04    |
 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100    | 2021-01-05    |
 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100    | 2021-01-06    |
 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100    | 2021-01-07    |
---+------------+------------+--------+---------------+
```

I want to make the operation date a row according to the range of start date and end date and input the same information.

Can you help? I've done a lot of searching, but I can't find a suitable answer.

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: @FaNo_FN I am using Redshift. It doesn't matter if it's MySQL 8.0 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `RECURSIVE CTE` like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT id, start_date, end_date, amount, start_date AS operation_date 
FROM table1 
 UNION ALL
SELECT id, start_date, end_date, amount, operation_date+INTERVAL 1 DAY 
FROM cte 
 WHERE operation_date+INTERVAL 1 DAY <= end_date)
  SELECT * 
    FROM cte ;
```

> | id | start_date | end_date | amount | operation_date |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100 | 2021-01-01 |
> | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100 | 2021-01-02 |
> | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100 | 2021-01-03 |
> | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100 | 2021-01-04 |
> | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100 | 2021-01-05 |
> | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100 | 2021-01-06 |
> | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 | 100 | 2021-01-07 |

[Here's a demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e8643b4257644ef5cb9af06d0c3dc88)